# FileName in OpenFileDialog appears empty

Tags: c#, openfiledialog

I have two radio buttons and a regular button - *button2*.

I've created an if else statement that checks which of the radio buttons is clicked and accordingly preforms a given task. In particular, if:

- Radio button 1 is clicked: Ask's to select one pdf file, opens a axAcroPDF1 connection and outputs the OpenFileDialog FileName into a textbox
- Radio button 2 is clicked: Something else
- No radio button is clicked: Sends a messege.. select a file.

This is my attempt:

```
    {

        if (radioButton1.Checked == true)
        {
            OpenFileDialog ofd = new OpenFileDialog();
            ofd.Filter = "PDF|*pdf";

            if (ofd.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
            {
                axAcroPDF1.Show();
                axAcroPDF1.src = ofd.FileName;
            }

            textBox1.Text = ofd.FileName;

            MessageBox.Show(ofd.FileName);
        }


        else if (radioButton2.Checked == true)
        {
            OpenFileDialog ofd3 = new OpenFileDialog();
            ofd3.Filter = "PDF|*pdf";
            textBox1.Text = ofd3.InitialDirectory + ofd3.FileName;

            if (ofd3.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
            {
                axAcroPDF1.Show();
            }
        }

        else if (radioButton2.Checked == false & radioButton1.Checked == false)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Please select a processing option");
        }

        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error.");
        }

    }
```

The issue is that I can't extract the FileName string in:  `textBox1.Text = ofd.FileName;`

Basically, this returns an empty string. I'm not sure how this is possible, when in fact the  axAcroPDF1.src successfully opens the selected pdf.

Any ideas?

Comment: Just move `textBox1.Text = ofd3.FileName;` into `if` - Note: `OpenFileDialog.FileName` will have a value after `OpenFileDialog.ShowDialog()` and `InitialDirectory` is `string.Empty` as default  -HTH  ;).

Comment: FYI, your last `else` will never be hit and can be removed. Your last `else if` is redundant (failing the first two tests implies the third)...you can replace *that* with an `else`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is the `ofd.ShowDialog()` method which populates the `ofd.FileName` property.

Following the logic of your code:

For checkbox 1, you do the right thing to check the appropriate return of `ofd.ShowDialog()` before you access your `axAcroPDF1` but there is no check that the user selected a file before you display the name in the checkbox.

For the checkbox 2 scenario, you are trying to access the `ofd3.FileName` before it is set by running the `ofd3.ShowDialog()` method.

The crucial point here is that `ofd3.ShowDialog()` is the point in your code where the dialog pops for the user.

You will want to move all of your calls to `ofd.FileName` and `ofd3.FileName` inside their respective `if` checks on the dialog.

Answer (score 1):

```
//Try this one    
if (ofd.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
            {
                axAcroPDF1.src = ofd.FileName;
                axAcroPDF1.Show();
                textBox1.Text = ofd.FileName;
            }
```